# Developing a file format using continous saving and versioning through SharePoint

Tags: c#, sharepoint, versioning, onedrive, file-format

Well, I found a lot of stuff to this question but unfortunately only bits and pieces and nothing that specific for someone who looks for a starting point.

Draft:
I plan a file format which is derived from BagIT. I want to implement it as a class library in c#.net.

Environment: Office 365 (SharePoint Document List) synced to Windows 10 by OneDrive.

This are the two planned features:
- "Versioning" or better "Diff", like for example in Word
- Continous saving also like in Word or better like in all Office apps

For those not familiar with this features: If you are working in Office 2017, and your file is saved on a SharePoint drive (don't know exactly about OneDrive privat), than you can swich on "continous saving" (don't know the english term). With this your work will always be saved and you don't need to save manually. Works on OneDrive and SharePoint.
If you have SharePoint and you are using the versioning feature of it, than you can Word (don't know of other Office apps) let show the differences between the versions.

The "don't knows" are not the point.

I am searching for an outline, a starting point. Is it possible at all or is it only usable by Microsoft (at the moment)?

So it is SharePoint and C# (.net)

Links would be nice,
an outline also for other readers/potential questioners would be better.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: These questions are way to broad for SO. They are matters for discussion not question/answer. As you are developing your library and have a specific question about your code, please add another question.

Comment: It ist, as I see it, very specific:

Comment: It ist, as I see it, very specific: 
I need a documentation about Microsoft SharePoint programming for the features versionig and continous saving (dont'know if it is called this way in english).
Just c#, .net, VisualStudio. Microsoft, no third party.

Answer (score 0):

No I found the answere myself. For all with the same question: It ist in the REST-API. With it you can download different versions and diff them yourself.

I didn't found continous saving, but I think it is somwhere in this documentation. If someone knew it right now, than it would be nice if you could shorten my search. Otherwise I will send the link when I find it myself.

Here the link:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/api/driveitemversion_get